# optimal way to prepend a file in php

Tags: php, file, io, prepend, fseek

Prepend a string to a file in php

- Size of file can be very large.
- Need an optimal solution while keeping performance as the key factor.

This is what i have so far

```
    function prepend($string, $filename) { 
        $context = stream_context_create (); 
        $fp = fopen($filename,'r',1,$context); 
        $tmpname = md5($string); 
        file_put_contents($tmpname,$string); 
        file_put_contents($tmpname,$fp,FILE_APPEND); 
        fclose($fp); 
        unlink($filename); 
        rename($tmpname,$filename); 
    }
```

Comment: What do you have so far? What exactly do you want?

Comment: function prepend($string, $filename){
 $context = stream_context_create ();
 $fp = fopen($filename,'r',1,$context);
 $tmpname = md5($string);
 file_put_contents($tmpname,$string);
 file_put_contents($tmpname,$fp,FILE_APPEND);
 fclose($fp);
 unlink($filename);
 rename($tmpname,$filename);
}

this is what I have found. not sure if it offers the most optimal performance for large files.

Comment: Is there a reason why you must prepend to a single file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prepend file to begining??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332262/how-do-i-prepend-file-to-begining)