# Why does fopen('file.txt', 'r+') followed by write() truncate the file?

Tags: php, fopen

I test this PHP code on windows and it first removes the file.txt contents and then write the new contents on it.

```
$f = fopen('file.txt', 'r+');
fwrite($f, "first-time");
fclose($f);
```

Every time I execute this code and see file.txt, it has ONE "first-time" in it.

I expect it to prepend "first-time" to the old file. like:
`first-timefirst-timefirst-time` and so on.

Why r+ acts like w+ in making zero length?

Comment: Could you tag this with what language it should be?  And tell us in your question?  And what outcome are you expecting?

Comment: I pressume language you're using is php. In this case, "r+" mode places the file pointer at the beginning of the file and this is why it overwrites each time you run the code. You need to use "a" (or "a+") mode. This will place file pointer to the end of the file. Like so: `$f = fopen('file.txt', 'a')`;

Comment: -1: _Read the documentation for functions that you use._ Everything you need is there.

Comment: But @Davit I want to append that at the first, not the end. I can use file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() in order to do that but I want to see how it is possible with fopen. tnx

Comment: @user3449439 Please accept my answer then, if it does what you want.

Comment: It does but I knew that. My question is why r+ acts like w+ in making zero length

Comment: @user3449439: "Appending" means "adding to the end". What you are asking for, then, is "prepending". Did you perform any research into how to do this?

Comment: BTW you spelt "first" wrong. I've fixed your title as it accused a function of "not working" when in fact you simply failed to look up what it does.

Comment: OK sorry for my bad english. I meant prepend

Comment: @user3449439 Thanks for the clarification. Would be nice if you could reconsider my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question: Your code does not truncate the file, but simply overwrites the previous content.

Quick and dirty solution for the behaviour your want to achieve:

```
<?php
$file_data = "Stuff you want to add\n";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('file.txt');
file_put_contents('file.txt', $file_data);
?>
```

Comment: Read his question, he wants to append at the beginning = prepending.

Comment: it doesn't use fopen and I don't like such script because it's not neat. unfortunately I think r+ acts like w+ in making that file to zero bytes.

Comment: You did not specify that it has to use fopen. It is neat enough, especially if you obviously are not familiar with fopen.

Comment: @tholu: "append at the beginning" makes no sense. If he means prepending he should say prepending.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think he is not a native English speaker. But you see that obviously my code does what he wants. It would be fair to remove your downvote here.

Comment: According to the discription in php.net . r+ should do the work. But I don't know why I should get the contents first and then append it and after it write. :| so what doesn r+ here?

Comment: @user3449439 You have to understand, that when you put the pointer at the beginning, it just starts to write there. It does not move the existing data, it just overwrites it. That's why you get the contents, piece it together in memory and write the result back to the file.

Comment: Ohh. so it overwrites it. It was the answer that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
The answer can be found here:
[How do I prepend file to beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332262/how-do-i-prepend-file-to-beginning)

According to the [PHP fopen manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'r+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the **beginning** of the file.
>
> 'a+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the **end** of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

```
$f = fopen('file.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($f, "fisrt-time");
fclose($f);
```

So if you'd like to append content, use a+ mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what benefit there is in repeating the code in the question. You don't even write any prose to explain your answer.

Comment: Everybody should read the question, he wants to append at the beginning = prepending!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I accidentally submited it while pressing tab and enter. I see stackoverflow doesn't show that the answer is beeing actively edited. Thanks for the downvotes anyway.

Comment: Tricky language question.

Comment: @zeldi Please see my answer - I guess you downvoted that, too.

Comment: @tholu: I haven't woted anybody's answer. I guess it's just an active/hot question with tricky word phrasing (append at the beggining), getting tons of editors. Your solution works, albeit it can be tricky with large files.