# Adding Data on top of HTML page using PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I am using the php post function to add data into an HTML file.
Every time i use it the data is added in the bottom of the page.
How can i make it to add it on the top..??

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');  
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];

$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
date_default_timezone_set("India/Kolkata");
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

**I Am new in coding**

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332262/how-do-i-prepend-file-to-beginning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prepend file to beginning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332262/how-do-i-prepend-file-to-beginning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to get the full content of your file, concatenate it with the new data at the beginning (new data + old data), and overwrite the file with this new content.