# How to write the last result in the first line of a file with php file_put_contents?

Tags: php, file-put-contents

Can anyone tell me how can I get the last result in the first line of a PHP return rather than having the last result in the last line. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$ip_get = date("Y/m/d") ." ". date("h:i:sa") . "    " . getRealIpAddr() . " " . 
PHP_EOL ;
$filename1 = 'iplogsget.csv';
file_put_contents($filename1, $ip_get , FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

At the moment, it outputs something like:

```
2021/07/22 12:51:58pm XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
2021/07/22 12:55:58pm XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

And I would like this kind of output instead:

```
2021/07/22 12:55:58pm XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
2021/07/22 12:51:58pm XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332262/how-do-i-prepend-file-to-beginning/3332403 help?

Comment: @Nico Haase Thanks it helped me perfectly I've replaced $prepend ="prepend me please" by my variable $ip_get and it works

Comment: @AndreaOlivato  Thanks it helped me perfectly I've replaced $prepend ="prepend me please" by my variable $ip_get and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ip_get = date("Y/m/d") ." ". date("h:i:sa") . "    " . getRealIpAddr() . 
" " . PHP_EOL ;
$filename1 = 'iplogsget.csv';
$prepend = $ip_get;
$fileContents = file_get_contents($filename1);

file_put_contents($filename1, $prepend . $fileContents);
?>
```